# C++ redefinition of function

Tags: c++

I have a base class and 3 separate derived classes. All of the .hpp files are structured the same.

The .hpp which doesn't work:

```
#ifndef CAESARCIPHER_HPP
#define CAESARCIPHER_HPP
#include "Cipher.hpp"
#include<string>

class CaesarCipher : public Cipher {
    public:
        CaesarCipher(Key key)
            : Cipher{ key } {}
        
        std::string getCipherTypeString() const override {}
};
#endif
```

The .cpp of it (haven't implemented anything yet):

```
  #include "CaesarCipher.hpp"
    #include "Cipher.hpp"
    #include<iostream>
    
    CaesarCipher::CaesarCipher(Key key)
        : Cipher{ key } {}
    
    std::string CaesarCipher::getCipherTypeString() const {
        return "";
    }
```

One .hpp that does work:

```
 #ifndef ASCIICIPHER_HPP
    #define ASCIICIPHER_HPP
    #include "Cipher.hpp"
    #include<string>
    
    class AsciiCipher : public Cipher {
        public:
            AsciiCipher(Key key)
                : Cipher{ key } {}
           
            std::string getCipherTypeString() const override {}
         
};
    #endif
```

The base.hpp class looks like this:

```
typedef uint64_t Key;


    #ifndef BASE_HPP
    #define BASE_HPP
    #include <string>    

class Cipher {
    Key key_;
    public: 
        Cipher(Key key){}
        
        virtual std::string getCipherTypeString() const {}
       
        
};
    #endif
```

Errors:

```
CaesarCipher.cpp:6:15: error: redefinition of 'CaesarCipher'
CaesarCipher::CaesarCipher(Key key)
              ^
./CaesarCipher.hpp:9:9: note: previous definition is here
        CaesarCipher(Key key)
        ^
CaesarCipher.cpp:9:27: error: redefinition of 'getCipherTypeString'
std::string CaesarCipher::getCipherTypeString() const {
                          ^
./CaesarCipher.hpp:12:21: note: previous definition is here
        std::string getCipherTypeString() const override {}
                    ^
```

The problem is that 2 of the derived classes work perfectly but for one I get the above mentioned error for all of the functions. They look all the same just with changed names etc.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] of code and full error message.

Comment: Provided code is wrong, as you don't return for non-void return-type methods...

Comment: Shall we assume, in the *real* code that reproduces the actual error you should be including *verbatim* in your post but chose not to, that `Base(Key key)` (a) actually gets the definition of what a `Key` is from... somewhere, and (b) doesn't leave off the trailing semi-colon and/or implementation?

Comment: The error message is clear: you are defining the constructor `CaesarCipher(Key key)` in the `.hpp` file _and_ in the `.cpp` file. Probably what you want is to _declare_ it in the `.hpp` file and define it in the `.cpp` file. To do this, just use the line `CaesarCipher(Key key);` in the `.hpp` file, without `: Cipher{ key } {}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

- Define the type `Key`.
- Provide the missing body for the definition of `Base::Base(Key)`.
- Add a return statement to all functions that return non-void.

That should fix the errors that you are getting.